# Converting resultSet to arrayList and printing it out

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to convert a result set with 2 columns into an arraList of arrays. To check my code I then print it out. For that purpose I made a little table compromised of 2 columns á 5 rows.

Problem is that my test print prints out 5 times my original table. So now I'm confused. Is my way of converting the resultSet wrong or am I not printing right? Could somebody help?

Code:

```
public static void partner() {
    ArrayList <int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    String select = "SELECT ID, age FROM individuen WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 40 " +
    "AND Familienstand IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";

    DBController dbc = DBController.getInstance();
    dbc.initDBConnection();


    try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);

        int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next()){
            int[] row = new int[columnCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount ; i++){
                row[i] = rs.getInt(i + 1);
            }
            result.add(row);

        }
        Iterator<int[]> it = result.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            for (int[] arr : result) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
                it.next();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using it     it.next();

Comment: Don't I have to use it to get the next element in the arrayList?

Comment: two times you are traversing your result, it.hasNext() will return you true if it contains more values,

Comment: try my answer code, and let me know is it working or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep only one loop either `for` or `while` loop.

```
   for (int[] arr : result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't +1, because I don't have enough points. But I would, if I could. Your code works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested iteration over your `ArrayList`, which means you iterate over the `ArrayList` multiple times (the number of times being the `size()` of the `ArrayList`).

You just need a single for loop :

```
    for (int[] arr : result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

or a single while loop :

```
    Iterator<int[]> it = result.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(it.next()));
    }
```

not both.

Comment: Same to you as to khAn. Thanks a bunch.